# Android MediaPlayer issue

Tags: android, media-player

I have followed the steps to create my media player object but I cant understand why it is not playing the music track. I used the following code:

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.create(this, R.raw.testmed); 
    mp.setVolume(100, 100);


    mp.start();
```

but no sound is playing through the emulator, and furthermore when i check the method mp.isPlaying() it returns false. What have I missed?!

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call all methods necessary to actually start the player. Take a look at [Android Media Player state diagram](http://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif)

I think you need to prepare the player before starting. When the player is prepared, it can be started. This is done through a `onPreparedListener`:

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.create(this, R.raw.testmed);
mp.setVolume(100, 100);
mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mp.prepare();
```

Then you will need to define this and it should work:

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
   mp.start();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't setVolume receive floats between 0 and 1?  mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f) will maximize the volume, I believe.

Comment: I've used it like that and didn't encounter any problems -- where does it say though that the values should be between 0 and 1?

Comment: I saw it in a tutorial somewhere; here's an "old" thread talking about it, but no definitive sources... http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/f1848285f8f3b60c

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for the addition though. Too bad the specs don't really clarify this.